# Are there any significant changes in German grammar since 1975?

Tags: grammar

I've decided to revise my German, after a pause. In home I came across a textbook called 
 "Deutsch Intensiv - Grundkurs für Ausländer", VEB Verlag Enzyklopädie, Leipzig 1975 - with around 700 pages exercises, grammar and so on. Very convenient for self-study.

Are there any changes in the grammar since 1975 because I've seen some words that nowadays are not used anymore - like 'Er ißt(essen in Präsens)' instead of 'Er isst'

Comment: You cannot possibly have missed the orthography reform of 1996, can you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996

Comment: The spelling rules have changed (google Rechtschreibreform). Grammar should be pretty much the same. Ofc. there are (slight) differences in style between 1975 German (esp. as spoken in the former DDR, where your book is from) and contemporary German.

Comment: I recall that we had a similar question about a year ago, but I can't find it right now..

Comment: Judging by title and size of the textbook and by the fact that you seem to study mostly from just one book it won't matter that much. If you learn just from one book there will be much more "negative" influences from your first language than from the outdatedness of that book.

Answer (score 1):

If you adhere to the *grammar* laid out in that book, you'll speak correct German albeit possibly out of style.

But you should respect the Orthography reform from 1996, which this book doesn't know of.

Comment: Well, even if he doesn't respect the orthography reform, I'm sure he'll *speak* correct German.